# Modifying layer properties for contents of collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I'm having mixed results when modifying the `layer` properties of an UIImageView. In a `UICollectionView`, I have `UICollectionViewCells` that have a single `UIImageView` in them. I want those images to look like circles, thus, in my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, I override `layoutSubviews` and placed my code there, like so:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  image.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(image.bounds) / 2
  image.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

However, I was getting unreliable results. Sometimes, the images are perfect circles (as intended), but sometimes they're squares with rounded edges, that may or may not become circles if you scroll through the `collectionView`.

Where is the best place to put this code?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the image. You need to have square images to create circles using cornerRadius. You can achieve this by setting the width constraint for the image and then setting the aspect ratio to 1:1.

Comment: I'm asking about where to put this code, not about finding the right `cornerRadius` value.

Comment: Don't be surprised to not get perfect circles then. `layoutSubviews` should be used for adjusting layout in case autolayout or autoresizing is not enough. But you need to change `cornerRadius` every time your cell is about to be displayed to recalculate radius based on width of the image so in this case I'd go with `collectionView(_:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:)` and some helper method in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass to do the layer setup so you don't get messy controller.